# I can't call a function in else if statement

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void Invalid_input(int& num1, int& num2) 
{
    while (!cin)
    {
        cout << "You entered an incorrect value!" << '\n';
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cout << "Please input again : ";
        cin >> num1 >> num2;
    }
}

int main() {
    while (1) { 
        int num_of_tower = 0, num_of_disk = 0;

        cout << "Please select the number of towers and disks" << '\n'
            << "tower and disk : ";
        cin >> num_of_tower >> num_of_disk;

        if (!cin) Invalid_input(num_of_tower, num_of_disk);
        
        else if (num_of_tower < 2)
            Invalid_input(num_of_tower, num_of_disk);
    }
}
```

This is just part of the whole code. I can't call the function, `Invalid_input`, in the `else if` statement (for example, after an input of 1 and 3).

Excluding this function call, all operations are performed. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Invalid_input` function ***is being called*** … but it's not doing anything! This is because, for an input of `1` for `num_of_tower` and a valid input for `num_of_disk`, there will not be an error on the `cin` stream, so the `while` loop in your function won't run (because the `while (!cin)` test will be *false*).

What you should do is to change that `while() {...}` loop into a `do { ... } while();` loop, which will always run at least once, even if `cin` is not in an error state:

```cpp
void Invalid_input(int& num1, int& num2)
{
    do {
        cout << "You entered an incorrect value!" << '\n';
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cout << "Please input again : ";
        cin >> num1 >> num2;
     } while (!cin);
}
```

You might also like to add a further check in that function, to ensure that the first input given is at least 2 (as in the `main` function):

```cpp
//...
        cin >> num1 >> num2;
     } while (!cin || num1 < 2);
}
```